# Hello, I need advice on making collision for a game I made in processing

Tags: processing, collision

I am making a version of the Atari game "Centipede" for my computer science class. I need help creating the collision for my code. I need to make it so when the bullets hit a part of the centipede, the game detects it and the part that got hit goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty broad question, but I'll try to help in a general sense.

You need to read up on [collision detection](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection).

First you probably want to break your centipede down into individual rectangles. For each rectangle, check whether it's colliding with the bullet.

You might consider **point-rectangle collision detection**, where you check whether the point is inside the rectangle. This will work if your bullet is a small point.

Or you might consider **rectangle-rectangle collision detection**, where you check whether two rectangles are overlapping. Use this if your bullets are larger than a point. Even if your bullet is a circle, you can usually get away with this kind of collision detection.

Please try something, and if you get stuck, then please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates where you're stuck. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

A simple implementation would be as follows: 
1. Designate an array that represents the pixel positions of the centipede 
 
2. Designate another array that represents the pixel positions of the bullet 
 
3. Update each array's values based on the sampling rate of your game and check to see if there is any overlap. (Ideally have this as a separate thread) 
 
4.Any overlap is indicative of a collision, so have some sort of collision handler function, which deletes the part of the centipede hit, that is triggered anytime an overlap event occurs.